# conditional ば with だ？

Tags: grammar, conditionals, copula

I found this:

```
でも、考えてみればだ。
```

Actually this is the first time I've seen a だ with a conditional together. What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any academic knowledge, but my sense as a Japanese speaker is that it has the role of emphasizing the speaker's words.
That is something you see in novels, but I don't think it is used very often in everyday life.
From a Japanese point of view, it may give the impression of someone who is assertive.

The following is just my imagination.
The word "だ" has the meaning of fact or assertion, which may have been derived to include the meaning of emphasis.